# $X_n = \text{Bin}(n,\frac{\lambda}{n})$ for $\lambda > 0$. Show $M_{X_n}(t)$ converges to the MGF of Poisson($\lambda)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

$X_n = \operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{\lambda}{n})$ for $\lambda > 0$. Show $M_{X_n}(t)$ converges to the MGF of Poisson($\lambda)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

So far I got
MGF of $$\operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^\infty(e^tx)^x/x!$$
MGF of $$\operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{\lambda}{n})=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}{n\choose x}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^x(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-x}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}{n\choose x}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^x(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-x}$$

I can see that $n \choose x$ as n goes to infinity will be $\frac1{x!}$, but I don't know how they got the $e^{-\lambda}$ and $x^x$. I could be wrong but I feel like $(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-x}$ just becomes 1 and $(\frac{\lambda}{n})^x$ becomes 0, which wouldn't really work out.

Comment: Do oyu know characteristic functions? And yours MFG of the Poisson and binomial r.v. are wrong. Note that the MGF is a function that measures, for each $k$, $P(X=k)$.

Comment: No we literally just learned this so I don't know the characteristic functions. I don't think my MGF for Poiss is wrong. The Bin might be

Comment: My bad, I read PMG instead of MGF. But still, the MGF for the Poisson is $\exp(\lambda(e^t-1))$, and that is not what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment generating function of a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is

$$M_P(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nt}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{t}\lambda)^n}{n!}=e^{-\lambda}e^{e^t\lambda}=e^{(e^t-1)\lambda}$$

The moment generating function of a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$  is

$$M_B(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n e^{kt}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(e^tp)^k(1-p)^{n-k}=(e^tp+1-p)^n$$

Now let $p=\dfrac{\lambda}{n}$ in the latter, the MGF is

$$M_B(t)=\left(e^t\frac\lambda n+1-\frac\lambda n\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{(e^t-1)\lambda}{n}\right)^n$$

Which tends to $e^{(e^t-1)\lambda}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I understand everything except how $(1+\frac{(e^t-1)\lambda}{n})^n$ goes to $e^{(e^t-1)\lambda}$ as n goes to infinity

Comment: @user8714896 Is it clearer if I write $\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n\to e^x$?